# How to assign separate pseudo link states for separate classes of links?

Tags: html, css

I have a download button and a simple link. I styled the download button with the needed pseudo classes like this:

`a:active`, `a:hover`, and `a:focus`

Now what for other class of links?

Will `a:active .newclass` do? It doesn't.

Comment: `a:active .newclass` searches for `.newclass` inside all `a` tags. To do what you want you should do `a.newclass:active`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the right CSS selector.

For a pseudoclass `:active` of a link of class `.newclass` you should use:

```
a.newclass:active
```

This will affect any link looking like this:

```
<a href='#' class='newclass'></a>
```

For a link with class `.inner` within an active link of class `.outer` you should use:

```
a.outer:active .inner
```

This will affect any link looking like this:

```
<a href='#' class='outer'>
  <a href='#' class='inner'></a>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS selector with this one

```
a.newclass:active
```

Otherwise you will looking for elements with the `.newClass` class **INSIDE** your `a` tags